# Caused by: Must include Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to use snapshots

Tags: android, google-play-games, android-googleapiclient

I have a **game app in Google Play store.** It implements [Google's Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) feature.

I haven't updated the app in months, and **from one day to another, users massively started to report the same error:**

```
Caused by: Must include Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to use snapshots!
```

They cannot save their games.

My first idea was **Google must have messed up something** because **I didn't update the app at all**, and it **was working very fine**, and from one day to another this issue popped up massively.

---

**The error message is incomprehensible for me, because I do have this scope included in my Google login as it follows:**

---

```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .requestId()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .build();
```

Of course I have it, otherwise it wouldn't work.

It was working perfectly, more over, it was working for almost a year now without any modification on my part.

So the next thing I was thinking alright, let's test it at least. So **I downloaded my own app from Playstore and tried a login and a save ...and for my greatest suprisement, it does work for me.**

**I cannot reproduce the error at all.** I tried with several Google accounts, tried with several uninstall-reinstall, tried with Google Play Games, also tried without it. **I'm absolutely clueless.**

The whole situation is a pain in the a. because:

1. I did not changed the application code, only the server side (Google's) code could change
2. I cannot reproduce the error, because with the very same application the feature works for me

I'm literally thinking about implementing my own Saved Games feature with server side code and everything because this is incomprehensible and hilarious. Users are writing to me and I cannot see a thing, cannot change a thing. Absolutely no way to start from this error.

Any response is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The same here, have you found any solution? 

We had a game released two years ago, giving monthly updates every month. we have +1M users , we've tested google save games many times in past an no problem, now it's about one month that it has stopped working suddenly, giving us the same error as you.

Comment: @JaamySK I didn't find the solution but players reported if they logout from Play Games then login, and start the app from Play Games that would solve the issue. Also, this error just disappeared for me after a few weeks. Google doing its thing again.

Comment: logging in/out seems not working for us, but anyway thanks for your answer, we will also share if we found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your code, the problem happens when the user sign up and do not give permission to the game to create and manage its own configuration data in Google Drive.

Now Google default behavior is for this permission to be denied, that's why you suddenly start facing this problem.

[image]

[Google have fixed it for unity plugin already](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2852)

Comment: And why I never saw this permission dialog? I tried several log-out, log in. And my players doesn't talk about this dialog neither, I assume they don't see it neither. Is this some bad design bug by Google? What would be the solution?

Comment: I am not sure why it does not show for everyone but it start showing to a lot of people.  the screenshot is from Samsung device with Android 11.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi was this the problem? did it help?

Comment: Honestly don't know, because I still never saw this dialog. Nor my players. Is there a way to force show this dialog?

Comment: You should try it from a new device, a one that did not install your app before and preferably with Android 11. if you send me the link, I will be more than happy to verify it, I have multiple test devices. but I am 99% sure that this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for your help I do really appreciate it my man, but it wouldn't solve my problem. My players don't have "new devices" for a fresh install, nor an Android 11. Google is messing up my product and I don't see a way out of this. So annoying.

Comment: Why don't you ask for permission again if you don't have access to drive. May be using a custom dialog to explain the issue to the players?

Comment: Why don't you report it to Google, they've fixed it for unity plugin https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2852